# How can I get the KVM virtual machine's data?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm-switch

I have a KVM virtual machine in my Dedicated Server, but I forgot the VM's password.

There is data in my VM, how can I get it? Is there any way to reset its password like in rescue mode/single user model?

Or is there any way to load the virtual data disk by another virtual machine?

---

**EDIT-01**

The VM OS is CentOS 7.2.
I manage the VM by libvirt.
disk type is SCSI, it is `vmdk` file.

Comment: What image format were you using for the VM's disk? What OS is installed in the VM? Do you manage KVM by hand or via libvirt?

Comment: edited my post.